# From a list of numeric values, create a list of indices

Tags: r, list

I have a list of numeric vectors:

```
a <- list(c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8), c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

> a
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1] 4 5 6 7 8

[[3]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

I want to create a list where each element corresponds to values from 1 to the max value in the original list "a". The values in each element of the new list are the *indices* in the original list containing the focal value.

For example, the first element in the result contains the indices in "a" with the value 1. Because no element contains 1, the result is `NULL`. The second element contains the indices in "a" with the value 2, i.e. the first element, 1. The value 4 is found in element 1 and 2.

```
> res
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[2] 1 2

[[5]]
[2] 1 2

[[6]]
[3] 1 2 3

[[7]]
[3] 1 2 3

[[8]]
[2] 2 3

[[9]]
[1] 3

[[10]]
[1] 3
```

I tried this with nested loops, but it is taking too much time and growing lists within loops is very slow. I have 60,000 sublists in my main list, so is there vectorized solution for this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't see how you went from your example list of lists `a` to the list turned inside out, also called `a`. Or aren't they related to each other?

Comment: It's simple: names of the new list formed from 1 to `max(a[1..3])`, and values are names / indices of the old list, where new name is found as a value. E.g. value 1 is absent, in all sublists, so  it is `NULL`, value 2 found only in sublist `a[[1]]`, value 6 is found in all `a[[1]]`, `a[[2]]` and `a[[3]]`, sot (new) `a[[6]]` contains `c(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: Yep, thats how I want it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a base R way.

```
lapply(seq.int(max(unique(unlist(a)))), \(i){
  which(sapply(a, \(x) any(i == x)))
})
```

Comment: @maydin You're right, thanks. I was correcting the bug when you posted the comment.

Comment: Very nice way of coding! Could you explain the usage of `\(i)` and `\(x)` briefly?

Comment: @JKupzig The first loop variable `i` loops through all unique elements of the list and the second, `x`, is each list member (each vector) and  meant to check whether `i` is in that vector.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. Nested apply functions did the trick.

Comment: I think you may skip the `unique()`.

Comment: @Rui Barradas Cool! I guess the [backslash](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-use-the-new-function-symbol-in-r-programming-4-1-r-4-1-c7cd2ac27b98) as new function symbol in R programming  only works for R versions ≥4.1, right?

Comment: @Dion Yes, the new lambdas were introduced in R 4.1.0, for older versions of R it's still the anonymous function declaration `function(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
 searchInList <- function(list2search, e){
      idx2search <- 1:length(list2search)
      list2search2 <- lapply(list2search, `length<-`, max(lengths(list2search)))
      output <- matrix(unlist(list2search2), ncol = length(list2search2[[1]]), byrow = TRUE)
      idx <- apply(output, 1, function(x){ (e %in% x) } )
      return(idx2search[idx])
    }

result <- lapply(1:max(unlist(a)), function(x) { searchInList(a, x) } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `match` and `rapply`.

```
apply(matrix(rapply(a, \(x) !is.na(match(1:max(unlist(a)), x))),,length(a)), 1, which)
# [[1]]
# integer(0)
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] 2 3
# 
# [[9]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[10]]
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using base R:

```
apply(sapply(a, `%in%`, x = seq_len(max(unlist(a)))), 1, which)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(purrr)
a <- list(c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8), c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

i = 1:10
map(i, ~map_int(imap(a, ~(..3 %in% .x)*.y, i), ~.x[.y], .x) %>% .[. != 0])
```

The logic is to get a list of positions of `TRUE` values, and multiple this by the list element index. Here, the first element of the first vector, first element of the second vector, third element of the third vector form all matches, and thus the first element in the target list.

```
imap(a, ~(..3 %in% .x)*.y, i)
[[1]]
 [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0

[[2]]
 [1] 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0

[[3]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3
```